# How can I see what Caravan cards I have?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm in the Sierra Madre Casino right now, and I'm trying to collect all of the cards. So, I want to see what cards I already collected so that I don't waste time trying to find the same card again.

I checked my inventory thoroughly, but I can't find my cards listed under any of the tabs. I'm certain I've picked up at least five cards. How can I find out which cards I have?

Comment: Usually, Caravan cards appear at the "Misc" tab, but they are not sorted, you have to look for 6 of Hearts - Sierra Madre around all your other stuff.

Comment: That's so weird, because I checked my entire inventory thoroughly and didn't find a single card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Wilerson said in his comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239029/how-can-i-see-what-caravan-cards-i-have#comment327242_239029), Sierra Madre cards will appear unsorted in inventory under "Misc" tab...

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvMn0.jpg) an example of few cards I picked up during my play. The items are sorted alphabetically, so if you got Aces or Kings, they will be bit further in the tab.